# Using @SpanTag to tag values for Spring sleuth span does not provide a map to add multiple key value pair

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Hi We are using spring sleuth for tracing. To create new span we are using annotation @NewSpan and to add Tags to this new span we are using @SpanTag.
Issue we are facing is if we are passing a map as input to method we want to create tags for each key in that map. But @SpanTag creates single key and assigned map as its value.

Is there any way to do that using annotations.
    @NewSpan
    public void storeStreamToS3(@SpanTag("objectInputStream") final 
    BufferedInputStream objectInputStream,@SpanTag("s3Key") final String 
    key,@SpanTag("metadata") Map metadata) {}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `Tracer` api to do that.

```java
// The user code can then inject this without a chance of it being null.
@Autowired SpanCustomizer span;

void userCode() {
  span.tag(...)
  ...
}
```

Comment: can you provide some code references for same as i think it will need to require manually iterating through map

Comment: I entered the code above. It's as simple as that. iterate over the map and then call `spanCustomizer.tag("key", "value");`

Comment: I got it but agian my question is we are using annotation approach so that we should not need to create or pass tracer object from controller to all the way to DAO but using Spancustomizer we will need to write custom code to add keys in tags in every layer and we will need to pass this span object to all layer is there any annotation bases approach for same

Comment: So there's no other way to do that other than the one I've mentioned